# Raspberry PI Video Camera Board on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: camera, windows-iot

This is my first post here because I just received my Adafruit package that contains Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows IoT Core package. I'm a total beginner in this kind of software development (I'm a Web Developer) so please bare with me if I'm saying stupid things or asking stupid questions.

I was looking at the Raspberry Pi Video Camera board which connects directly to the main board through a special interface but I couldn't find any information regarding the software development in Windows 10 IoT regarding that camera - how that is exposed to the OS? Is "seen" directly like a video camera or how do I connect to that device?

Comment: Currently only USB camera support is enabled, like the MS Live cam.  Please be patient while the CSI drivers are made for IoT. https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/WebCamSample.htm

Comment: For any future readers, as of April 2017 there is still no support for CSI drivers nor any mention of it by Microsoft. This question is on the front page of my Google queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Raspberry Pi cameras connected to the CSI port do not work on Windows IoT core. They are fully supported on Raspbian.